# Java - Jdbc Connection throw NullPointerException

Tags: java, tomcat

I have webapplication which is running succesfully. Reporting module is there using core java. When the user click card sale then it show report , & 2nd time click on that working after 6 or 7th time clcik on same option it throw `NullPointerException` & it say `HTTP Status 500` . I oped the connection & closing it.

Please suggest any solution this.

Comment: What is the reason for negative flag?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but your question is not clear. How can we now why your server throws a nullpointer if we even don't have the code? Could you answer me if I ask you: "I am calling to my brother but after 6th call my phone is shutting down.Why is it so?"

Comment: Can you provide stacktraces, relevant code.  Without that it is very difficult to diagnose the problem.

Comment: NullPointerException is one of the easier bugs to diagnose and fix.  You get the name of the .java source file and line at which the exception occurred from the stack trace.  Open that file in a text editor, navigate to that line, and look at all the references you have.  One of them is null - figure out which one and give it a non-null reference.  That's it.  You don't need to come here and ask about such things.

Answer (score 2):

Run the application in a (remote) debugger session and set a breakpoint on `NullPointerException`. Then you either know the problem or have some code to show with your question.